# Prevent auto sorting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run the following query:

```
Select * 
From table 
Where ID In ('100', '20', '222', '1', '15')
```

When I run the following query, the resultset is returned ordered by `ID`. 
(ID is the primary key).

How do I ensure that the resultset is returned in the order I specified in `In ('')`.

Comment: `SELECT` doesn't order the results in any specific order and the output is not guaranteed to be an any order. If it is ordered by ID then it is just a co-incidence and you should not rely on it to be ordered without having an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly state the order of the results you want if you don't want the default sorting.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN ('100','20','222','1','15')
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN ID = '100' THEN 1
             WHEN ID = '20' THEN 2
             WHEN ID = '222' THEN 3
             WHEN ID = '1' THEN 4
             WHEN ID = '15' THEN 5
        END
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have Primary Key, then data is sorted and stored based on the primary key. In fact behind the Primary Key, SQL Server create a [Clustered Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described). **One of the characteristics of Clustered Index is that the data is always physically sorted based on it**.

If you need to show the data in custom order, you need to specify it using `Order By`

@Brad is currently provided a sample query which sort the data based on your `IN` Clause: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453671/1666800

Comment: _Data is always sorted and stored based on the primary key._ No. That is the default behavior. But it is possible to have a different cluster key or a heap organized table.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance thanks for the comment, I have updated the answer and eliminate the ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option.  The XML Parser will include a Sequence Number

```
Declare @List varchar(max) = '100,20,222,1,15'

Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@List,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) B  on A.ID=B.RetVal
 Order by B.RetSeq
```